# In nginx create multiple reverse proxies dynamically based on an environment variables

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Normally in an nginx configuration file, I can redirect the dynamic server data to another server by using a reverse proxy like:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://dynamic_address;
}

location / {
    # redirect everything to show the main SPA application
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires 7d;
}
location = /index.html { }
```

However if in my case I have multiple redirects, if I give them statically they are:

```
location /api/entry {
    proxy_pass http://dynamic_entry:8433;
}
location /api/rover {
    proxy_pass http://dynamic_rover:8444;
}

location / {
    # redirect everything to show the main SPA application
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires 7d;
}
location = /index.html { }
```

I, however, do not wish to hard code those addresses, rather those addresses need to be set based on an environment variable, which has a format like (format can be different):

```
dynamic_entry=/api/entry:dynamic_entry:8433;/api/rover:dynamic_rover:8444
```

Can I do this without creating a bash (or run another language like php) to modify the config file on docker launch/server start?